# Specialize template is_string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that overloads a lot of members for different types as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
Stream& operator << (Stream &Destination, const std::list<T, Allocator> &Value)

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
Stream& operator << (Stream &Destination, const std::vector<T, Allocator> &Value)
```

And now I'm trying to specialize it for strings.. I created an is string using:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_string : public std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<char*, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value || std::is_same<const char*, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value> {};

template<>
struct is_string<std::string> : std::true_type {};
```

and then I want to make it specialized as follows:

```
template<typename T = typename is_string<T>::value_type> //How?
Stream& operator << (Stream &Destination, const typename is_string<T>::value_type &Value)
{
    std::cout<<"HERE";
    return Destination;
}

//I can do:
template<typename T = std::string> //works fine.
Stream& operator << (Stream &Destination, const typename is_literal<T>::value_type &Value)
{
    std::cout<<"HERE";
    return Destination;
}
```

How can I fix the string one so that it works for all string types so that T is whatever string type passed?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to do this so that it specializes for all string types: char*, const char*, char[], const char[], std::string, etc..

Comment: Why checking if the type is string rather than directly specializing `operator <<` for `std::string`, `char const*` ... ?

Comment: Because I'd have to specialize for every possible type of string? std::string, const char*, char*, char[], const char[], etc..? I thought that if there was a way to do what I'm trying to do, it'd auto specialize for that type.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, You have overrides for `Stream& operator <<()` fo other types, why not a `const std::string&` as well? I've not tried it, admittedly, but it *seems* it would do what you want (I think) ?

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully it makes sense now? Or should I specialize for every string type?

Comment: Making the traits `is_string` or `is_literal` is as complicated as overloading `operator <<`

Comment: No it isn't. I added the entire is_string to the post just now. It detects every kind of string there is.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. You can pass a `const char *` to a function parameter of `const std::string&`. It won't be a direct reference, but it should send a copy to the function, if I understand your end-goal. Or just implement it against `const char *` and forward `const std::string& to it using `c_str()`. Both `char*` and `char[]` will naturally choose `const char *` as the one to hit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <ostream>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_string<T>::value, std::ostream &>::type
operator<<(std::ostream & o, T const & x)
{
    return o << x;  // or whatever
}
```

This enables the overload only if `T` satisfies the trait.

(You could also make all the ostream template parameters variable for additional flexibility.)